# Support for Thunderbolt connection devices in Linux?

Tags: kernel, hardware, thunderbolt

What is the current level of support for Intel Light Peak connection devices in Linux? Has anyone seen any of these in a Linux system?

http://www.intel.com/technology/io/thunderbolt/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a real Thunderbolt support is currently in kernel 3.12. Though not well-known, but it's supported as announced in the 3.12 release. And I'm running ubuntu 13.10 updated with kernel 3.12.0 on my NUC and Thunderbolt works perfectly with Caldigit Thunderbolt station, which gives me USB3/Eth/Audio/HDMI functionality without the needs to install any drivers. The true plug-and-play!

Answer (score 2):

The best information I've been able to find so far was [this proposal](http://www.linuxplumbersconf.org/2011/ocw/proposals/99) for a talk at the upcoming Linux Plumbers Conference by a member of Intel’s LAN Access Division (LAD):

> While there is no real immediate need for added software, LAD will be supplying initial software for peer-to-peer use in Linux and other OSes. LAD will also be working on enablement code for Open Source OSes so that others will be able to use that code. LAD may also supply other use case but initially only peer-to-peer will be done. LAD has not come up with all the use cases that the Open Source community and other are going to come up with for this technology.

The conference is scheduled for September 9th and I'm sure whatever he presents will be covered by typical Linux media, so I guess we'll know then.

Answer (score 2):

please also see this thread, where there is some updated information

[Is the Intel Thunderbolt interface supported in Ubuntu Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161964/is-the-intel-thunderbolt-interface-supported-in-ubuntu-12-04)

as of today, there is still no "real" tunderbolt support in ubuntu, sadly :(