# Is the Intel Thunderbolt interface supported in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, hardware, intel, thunderbolt

I was searching the web around one hour now, but still could not find a definite answer: **Is Intel Thunderbolt already working with Linux?**

I am especially interested in networking, so that I can transfer files from a Mac OSX Machine to an Ubuntu (Intel DZ77RE-75K or Gigabyte Z77X-UP5) Machine.
Any news/information on Ubuntu and Linux Kernel support for Thunderbolt?

Comment: On what Linux Distribution?

Comment: @Alvar The OP mentions `Ubuntu` as well as the `Linux kernel`.. I do believe that this indicates his interest in support for the Ubuntu distro, as well as support for the Linux kernel.. **;)**

Comment: What's wrong with Gigabit Ethernet? The initial applications for Thunderbolt mostly involve graphics cards...

Comment: The thunderbolt to HDMI out works with no extra setup for my MacBook Pro, though I do not know about the other functions (data, periferals etc.), and would be interested to know.

Answer (score 3):

As of May 2012, [support in the Linux kernel](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5NzE) was still buggy and being worked on. For example, hot-plugging did not work, while cold-plugging did, etc.

Considering that the new Linux kernel will only appear in Ubuntu 12.10 (October 2012), I think that's the earliest you can hope to expect partial Thunderbolt support in Ubuntu.

Comment: "Cold plug" works well for Ethernet adapter on current Ubuntu 12.10. "Hot plug" still doesn't... yet!

Comment: @Murphy I was reading last night that hot-plugging is working now. Can you confirm?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix sorry I haven't used Ubuntu for years now... I was bored of waiting for problems like these to be resolved. OSX just works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Actually thunderbolt support is added in the kernel 3.12 and it works on my NUC running ubuntu 3.10 and kernel 3.12.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? So is thunderbolt as of today fully supported in (Ubuntu) Linux?

Comment: @Nanofunk "fully supported" is a moving target I think. In the last couple of months revisions were made in Linux to "support more" of Thunderbolt 3.